# Generate OAuth 2.0 Access Token For PUT Request In Google Sheets API In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, google-drive-api, google-authentication

**GOAL**

I would like to update some information in a Google Sheets document though a web service. I don't mind if the data is public, but it seems like I need to get an OAuth token in order to use `PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}`as opposed to simply getting the data. However, I get back errors stating that I'm missing OAuth 2.0 credentials.

**EXPECTATIONS**

In order to do this, I assume that I need to first get credentials from [Google's Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) . I currently have an OAuth 2.0 client ID and API key through that console. The API key is used to read the data and the OAuth would be used to write data.

I then need to hit an endpoint of some kind with the OAuth information to get credentials that'll be used. I'm supposed to put this info into my `PUT` request. [This is the documentation I've found in regards to my request, but it's missing the authorization documentation.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

**QUESTIONS**

1) Where is the endpoint that I'm hitting to get a refresh token and access token in Google's OAuth 2.0 stuffs? I've heard it's something like `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`, but I'm not sure *how* to get the tokens. What do I need to pass? How do I pass that info? I can't find any documentation over it.

2) After getting these tokens, how do I incorporate them into the `PUT` request to the Google Sheets API? Do the tokens go into the `Authorization` header or the `access_token` query parameter or something?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to check the [Javascript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) for Sheets API first as it includes OAuth sign-in demo.

From the quickstart code, this is the part that calls the OAuth library:

```
 function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
 }
```

And here's me using the PUT request in an app I made:

```
function recordTimeInSheet(){

     var params = {
       "range":"Sheet1!"+A+":"+C,
       "majorDimension": "ROWS",
       "values": [
       ["bruceWayne","8:00AM", "5:00PM"]
      ],
     }
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('PUT', 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+myspreadsheetId+'/'+"values/"+"Sheet1!"+A+":"+C+"?"+'valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED');
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + myAccessToken);

    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
  }
```

Comment: Sorry that this wasn't explicitly stated, but I have tried this before. I couldn't get it working. Looking back at it, I realized that the reason it didn't work was because I was running my applications locally, which isn't supported by `gapi`. Is there a way around this or a way to _not_ use `gapi`?

Comment: you just need to start a local webserver to make it work (which means you need to have internet). sample is python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080  . . Google how to start a local server specific to your OS, but that's one way of doing it.